# Setting Google AppEngine Jetty version

Tags: java, node.js, google-app-engine, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have been trying to work out an issue that has recently started on our local development setup. We have two ways of running localhost. One is via Ecplise and it runs fine. We also have a run script using Node.js that will startup localhost via command line. Both were working fine, but now the version running via the run script is causing a few issues. The main issue is that when trying to load the website it gets stuck at "Waiting for localhost" and a bunch of the files are stuck at "Pending" like they won't load. I can get past it but it takes a bunch of reloading and disabling and enabling cache and it will eventually load.

So far I haven't found any specific error, but what I noticed in the request for the files there is a minor difference between the version running via Ecplise and the one running with the run script. The Ecplise version seems to to have Remote Address set to `127.0.0.1:8080` and Server set to `Jetty(9.3.7.v20160115)`, but the version run with the run script has Remote Address set to `[::1]:8080` and Server set to `Jetty(9.4.24.v20191120)`.

Does anyone know if this could cause something like this to happen and any idea how to set the Jetty version with Google AppEngine?

I do see in the pom.xml `9.3.7.v20160115` but I have no idea how we are getting `Jetty(9.4.24.v20191120)` and I have yet to find that value configured anywhere.

Edit: Here is a bit in my pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How are you verifying that the Jetty version in App Engine is 9.4.24.v20191120? Have you deploy the App Engine? Could you please share your pom.xml file to look how you are setting the Jetty version?

Comment: I added an edit with the Jetty configuration, not the entire pom.xml file.

I am using Google Devtools to see what version it's using. So the two version numbers I got from there. In the request you can see the version.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue with App Engine Flexible with Jetty and got the same issue as yours. Please let me know if it's happening also in your local environment.

Comment: Really? It's just localhost we are having the issue with currently. Production is just fine. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: It's related to Jetty and nothing specific with App Engine. It seems Jetty is overriding the configurations we specify or use for the Jetty version.

Comment: Ok sweet. Thanks for that. It confirms what I though. Now I have to see if I can get our node.js run scripts to run with 9.3.7 and see if that helps.

Comment: Not sure if you could have a quick look at the full pom.xml file. It's linked here: https://codeshare.io/5OPenP. Not really sure what is configured wrong but I can't seem to get the version the change.

Comment: Ignore that. I worked out that our run scripts are updating GAE on our development setup. If run via Eclipse it doesn't update and runs on an older version. So I just need to work out how to stop it auto-updating for now since the bug is in Jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the replies above we worked out that when running in Eclipse it was running an older version of Google Cloud SDK `199.0.0` and the run script was just updating the SDK. The version that got updated had a bad version of Jetty that has since been patched but the SDK hasn't.

I added `<cloudSdkVersion>199.0.0</cloudSdkVersion>` to the pom.xml file and the run script now is running `199.0.0` until the SDK gets patched with a working version of Jetty.